# How did Banner survive on Sakaar?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

How did Bruce Banner (when he is not the Hulk) survive on a planet like Sakaar or on Asgard?

Are these planets habitable for humans?

Comment: Guardians of the Galaxy established that most planets that the characters visit are completely compatible with humans (even things like gravity).

Comment: @Maslin see the answer of Paulie_D he had explain it very well with image that depicted scene where you can see Banner having conversation with Thor on planet Sakaar.

Comment: @GhotiandChips - "even things like gravity". Gravity would be the *most* likely thing to be believable. You should be saying "even things like atmosphere".

Comment: @WakeDemons3 Do you understand that what I was saying was shorthand for; every single extraterrestrial planet featured in the MCU so far (Asgard, Sakaar, Xandar, Maveth, Muspelheim, Morag, etc.) *all* feature the same gravitational pull as Earth. A movie like *Avatar* (2009) features Pandora with a weaker pull. You say "should be saying things like atmosphere", but that's perfectly obviously implied in my comment already, when I say "completely compatible with humans" as a response to the question "Are these planets habitable for humans".

Comment: The reason I brought up gravity as an aside is because that's a *less* obviously implied part of "completely compatible with humans", and yet potentially just as peculiar from a realism perspective when thought about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Are these planets habitable for humans?

## Yes

It's been established that many planets in the MCU will support Earth-born humans

Asgard was visited by Jane Foster...and she later joined Thor on Svartalfheim.

[image]

Peter Quill / Star-Lord visits a number of planets with no trouble in Guardians of the Galaxy including Xandar

[image]

Also recall that the Hulk is just Banner in giant green form (essentially)...he still has to breathe (at least as far as we know in the MCU). He might be tougher, stronger and more resistant than Banner but, basically, he's still a **human** albeit an *enhanced* one.

Comment: [It's not true that Hulk "still has to breathe"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/40067/73512). Moreover, there is no reason to assume Hulk is human, in fact the comics would lean toward the opposite, considering they refer to Banner as "the human form" (does it make sense for a human to "revert back to human form"?). I think that end-note section in your answer is not necessary

Comment: Looks like that person on the left requires assistance breathing in a human-suited atmosphere, though. Or maybe breathing masks are fashionable on Xandar.